# Token for user being viewed

Tags: users, tokens

I am formatting the user profile page in Drupal 8.9.2.

Are tokens available for the user being viewed (in user profile page), to display the user information?

I am using the *Token* and the *Token Filter* modules for this.
(edited: 8:44 AM 10 Sep 20)

Comment: For example, you're on a user page, e.g. /user/123, and you want to display information about the user with id 123 somewhere on the page via a token?

Comment: @sonfd: Exactly. For example consider a user field First Name, when I use the token available for user, in my case [user:field_fir] it does not work. I can see that it requires context but I am unable to find how to do it.

Comment: @sonfd Can you help me?

Comment: You seem to have the format correct, it should be something like `[user:field_custom]`. Ca you please update your question with more information around how you're using these tokens. Where are you placing them? Do other tokens work in the same place?

Comment: @sonfd I have created some user fields. Two of them are-
(1) Qualifications
(2) Registration no.  
Then, I created a custom block with token values.
Qualifications: [user:field_qualifications]
Text value: [user:field_qualifications:value]
Registration no.: [user:field_registration_no_]
Text value: [user:field_registration_no_:value]  
Then, I went to Configuration > People > Account settings > Manage Display > User Account > Manage Layout  
Then, I placed this custom block in a column.
But, this is not working.

Comment: @sonfd Then, to check, I replaced these values for current user token values  and this time they show correctly.

Comment: The output was(in the first case):- 
Qualifications: (blank)
Text value: (blank)
Registration no.: (blank)
Text value: (blank)

Comment: I think your approach is wrong because [current-user] token usually means the current logged in user. So, if you are logged in as the user 10, and you are in the udsedr/123 page you'll see data from user 10, not the user 123. You should use the User entity display page to display the user data in the user's page.

Comment: @sanzante: I am not using the tokens for 'current user', I am using the tokens for 'user', for example, I have a 'Qualifications' user field for which the token available is [user:field_qualifications], but when I use this token in a custom block it does not work.Perhaps it requires the context but I am unable to find how to do it. Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: I only notice the second code example. About my answer: users are fieldable entities just like nodes. Hence, you can manage the display of those fields in /admin/config/people/accounts/display.

Comment: @sanzante: Obviously, I can manage those fields with their label names in 'manage display'. But I want to place a custom block in the user profile page which contains the user information along with other text and html formatting. For example, let the 'Qualification' user field contains value 'MBBS' for a user. Let I want to place this text in the custom block. "He is [user:field_qualifications] 2008 batch."
But, it is not working. Other tokens are working, such as [site:name] etc. It means tokens are working but this specific token requires some other information. Any help?

Comment: You can template the user profile page so you don't need tokens and that custom block, just variables you pass to the user template. The custom block would be interesting if you reuse it in other places. If you only use it in the profile page I think is better to use the Drupal's templating system.

Comment: @sanzante: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem this way.
(1) I created a **View** to show desired user information.
(2) Then, I added a '**Contextual filter**' to point to the user being viewed. (with the options "*User ID > Provide default value > Type: User ID from route context*")
(3) Then, I selected '**REWRITE RESULTS**' and "**Override the output of this field with custom text**". As a result *replacement tokens* become available for user fields. I used that for formatting the Information according to the requirement.
Then, I placed this View block at the desired place.